# how to debug jquery code line by line in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    debugger
        $("a").click(function () {
            alert("Hello World..");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am very new to this jquery.I wanted to see my program flow of execution in chrome.What is the procedure for debugging jquery.My execution flow is not entering into the .click .But alert message is showing[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if You want to execute JS in chrome you have to do like this I am attaching an image
pls find it

go to console and type your JS and enter!

Comment: where u have attached an image.i have not got it

Comment: Please ensure that you make everything that shows the solution to the issue publicly assessable. This answer is useless to anyone coming across this page.

Comment: -1 for having a solution to the problem, but sending it in private mail instead of posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can install firebug lite for the chrome and in that you can debug by adding breakpoints and watches inside the jquery files used. I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to find your code in the sources tab of the developer tools and add a break point next to each line of the code you want to stop at, then refresh the page.